# can I fly out of Reynosa Mexico with my Texas ID and a copy of my birth certificate?. June 2020

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, mexico, domestic-travel

I am a US citizen but don't have a passport, and I'm not able to get one, because I have outstanding child support debts.

I would like to fly out from Reynosa, Mexico to Cabo San Lucas, Mexico. Will I be able to board the plane with just a Texas Driver's License, a birth certificate and a completed covid-19 form?

I need information that is current as of July, 2020.

Comment: Why is child support relevant here? Is it because you are under 18 years old? If so, some different regulations may apply. In such cases, the [rules](https://www.oma.aero/es/pasajeros/reynosa/informacion-de-viaje/preguntas-frecuentes.php) vary depending on if you are traveling alone or with an adult.

Comment: @mlc It means he can't get a US passport.

Comment: My Son is 28 with a masters in computer science from UT, there saying I still owe back child support and denied passport. I guess $3,200.00 per month 25 years ago wasn't enough.

Answer (score 4):

Flights.google.com shows that flights between Reynosa, Mexico and San Jose del Cabo, Mexico, all connect via Mexico City.

[This MEX Airport FAQ webpage](https://www.aicm.com.mx/en/passengers/faqs) contains the following text:

**Documents for traveling on a domestic flight**:

- Mexicans
  Boarding pass and an official identification (voter ID, passport, driver's license)
- Foreigners
  Boarding pass and valid passport

Thus, if you are a Mexican citizen and have a valid Mexican voter ID, Mexican passport, or Mexican driver's license, you can take these flights.

The documents you list in the question (birth certificate and Texas drivers license) do not meet the requirements set forth on the FAQ page.

Comment: it's been a bit since I had a connecting flight in Mexico, so I may be forgetting something, but I don't think they re-check your documents at Mexico City airport; however, the same (or very very similar) requirements are likely to apply on initial check-in at Reynosa or any other airport in Mexico.

Comment: +1.  Further to this it is not actually legal for foreigners to enter Mexico without a passport, and they must travel with a tourism permit once inside Mexico (passport is required to obtain tourism permit).  The traveler may be stopped and asked for either/both while traveling. While Mexico may let people in without asking to see the passport, it is a required travel document.

Comment: The OP could enter Mexico if he's a Mexican/US dual citizen.