# Travel to Mazatlan from Monterrey, do I need a passport?

Tags: air-travel, passports, us-citizens, mexico

I have recently been told we need to go Mazatlán and I live in Texas so we are going to take a bus from Laredo to Monterrey. I do not have a book passport but I do have a passport card. Will I be able to fly from Monterrey to Mazatlán with the US passport card, Texas DL?

Comment: Welcome to [Travel.SE]!  Here are some previously asked questions on this site that might help answer your question:  [117651](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117651/), [157663](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157663/), [29149](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29149/).  From those, it appears that you will need a book (not a card) to fly domestically in Mexico unless you're a Mexican citizen.

Answer (score -4):

**EDIT 2:** I found yet another source that proves my answer right.
IATA Travel Centre:
https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/MX-Mexico-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

I filled the form with a travel from Mexico to Mexico, 10 days (to avoid any VISA issues), adult traveling with a US passport card. The results says it pretty clear:

> - Summary: **No**, the documentation you hold is NOT sufficient for the journey you have specified.
> - Passport: Passport required.

You can fill it out yourself to see the results.

PS. I got redirected to IATA's online tool by Aeromexico, the flag carrier airline of Mexico.

**EDIT:** The answer stays the same.

> The passport card is not valid for **air travel except domestically within the U.S.**

According to Aeropuerto Internacional de la cuidad de México:

> Foreigners who want to travel on a domestic flight within Mexico need
> a boarding pass and a valid passport.

Despite its name, a passport card **does not count** as a "valid passport". The only exceptions are US domestic flights or land/sea border with specific countries (including Mexico). Any air travel outside the US, in a country that requires foreigners to carry a passport to board a plane (like Mexico does), **will require a passport book**.

---

No you will not.

Quoting from the U.S. DEPARTMENT of STATE - BUREAU of CONSULAR AFFAIRS:

> The passport card **cannot be used for international air travel**.

So you **cannot** **fly** to (EDIT: or within) Mexico with just a passport card. The passport card **can be used** as a valid ID **at land and sea crossings** between the US and Mexico. So if you were to drive to Mexico, or take any land or sea vehicle to cross the border, the passport card would be enough (along with whatever permits or visa you need for your activity).

Comment: The OP isn't flying into Mexico, though.  She's taking a bus (i.e., a land crossing) from Laredo to Monterrey, and then flying within Mexico from Monterrey to Mazatlán.  Her question is about whether the US passport card (and/or a Texas driver's license) is acceptable for a flight within Mexico.

Comment: Yes exactly, I called VivaAeroBus and they said I should be okay with a Texas DL. But I don’t want it to change when I get there and have to change my flight, so I wanted to see if anyone else has been in that situation..

Comment: @StephanieSandoval My bad, I assumed it was Monterey, TX. I updated the answer with the relevant informations, but it's still the same: passport card doesn't allow you to flight domestically inside Mexico as a foreigner.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks for the clarification, updated my answer. Passport cards do not allow domestic air travel in Mexico for foreigners.

Comment: Your first quote means that the passport card is not accepted for international travel, but it says nothing about whether it's usable *as ID* (a much lower bar) for domestic travel in Mexico.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Read the updated answer. Mexico domestic flights require a VALID PASSPORT. A passport card does NOT count as a valid passport for Mexico domestic air travel.

Comment: Yes, the second quote answers the question (and would be better with a link to the source), but I'm saying the first one does not.

Comment: I don't think the quote this answer relies on is an exhaustive list of documents they'll accept from foreigners on domestic flights. I am a foreigner who has often gotten onto flights with a resident card, and I once saw an American in line in front of me get on a flight (ZIH to MEX) with a US passport card. Volaris, e.g., [has a longer list of acceptable photo ID for foreigners](https://cms.volaris.com/en/travel-info/before-your-flight/travel-documents/). I can't say for sure a passport card is guaranteed to work, but I am sure foreigners aren't limited to passport books.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Here's the link about Aeropuerto Internacional de la cuidad de México documentation requirements: https://www.aicm.com.mx/en/passengers/faqs

Comment: @Dennis I trust more informations coming from Mexico City International Airport's website, rather than a low-cost airline.

Comment: Update 2: added another source. According to IATATC, US passport card is not sufficient for a US citizen to travel within Mexico on a domestic flight.

Comment: The proper answer would be that to travel withing Mexico a **Multiple Migratory Form** (FMM) is needed. Pre condition for this is a valid passport with more than 6 months of validity. [Visas to Mexico](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/finlandia/index.php/traveling/visas)

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's incorrect. A passport card is accepted to get a FMM, if arriving by land. Also OP is not asking about permits, such as FMM or visas.

Comment: @Mr_Bober But only for the border zone and Mazatlán is outside of that zone. [Instituto Nacional de Migración - Forma Migratoria Múltiple](https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html) 'The applicant is aware that the *card passport (Tarjeta Pasaporte)* can only be used in the border crossings by land and **for visiting the border zone**; it **might not be used to travel to the territory of the Mexican Republic** or used for international air trips.'

Comment: @Mr_Bober, I really don't think the IATA site is reliable for domestic travel requirements. It insists that an American needs a passport book for domestic flights in Canada as well, yet Air Canada (the "flag" carrier) doesn't preclude a passport card and additionally lists NEXUS and EDLs (and green cards for US residents) as acceptable too. And while Volaris lists a cogent set of documents that matches my experience the Aeromexico "for Mexicans" list includes a document (FM3) that was never for Mexicans and went out of use in about 2012. Who should I trust?

Comment: @MarkJohnson In either case, his question is about domestic flight, for which I already said he needs a passport book. The FMM requirements and details are irrelevant at this point.

Comment: @Dennis Interesting. I don't know who's right, but when in doubt about rules and laws it's always best to go with the stricter ones. Because if you pick the broader one and it's incorrect, you risk severe consequences. I found IATA's link directly on Aeromexico's website, in the section dedicated to which documents are needed for travel. That makes me think it's somewhat trustworthy for Mexico at least, otherwise why would an airline refer their customers to it?
Unfortunately I can't find any official government source about what documents are needed by foreigners for domestic air travel